# How to show mat-spinner for each row in mat-table in angular 6

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-material

I have a mat-table which displays list of executing Jobs. I have created two buttons(Stop and Re-Run) next to each row. However I want to create a mat-spinner which will only be displayed when a Job is running or when a user clicks on Re-Run Button.
I have created the spinner but it's showing for all rows when i click on Re-Run Button.
How do I show it only for the row on which I have clicked.

My html code:

```
 <!--  Code for Stop and Re-Run Buttons -->
        <ng-container matColumnDef="actions">
            <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> </mat-header-cell>
            <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element; let index = index">
                <button
                    mat-icon-button
                    (click)="stop_exec_job(element)"
                    matTooltip="Stop Executing the Job"
                    [disabled]="element.status == 'Completed'"
                >
                    <!-- Edit icon for row -->
                    <i class="material-icons" style="color:red"> stop </i>
                </button>
                <!-- Delete icon for row -->
                <button
                    mat-icon-button
                    (click)="re_run_job(element)"
                    matTooltip="Re-Run the Job"
                    [disabled]="
                        element.status == 'Running' ||
                        element.status == 'Pending'
                    "
                >
                    <i class="material-icons" style="color:green">
                        cached
                    </i>
                </button>
            </mat-cell>
        </ng-container>
        <!-- Code for Spinner -->
        <ng-container matColumnDef="spinner">
            <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> </mat-header-cell>
            <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
                <div *ngIf="displaySpinner;else doNotShowSpinner">
                    <mat-spinner></mat-spinner>
                </div>
                <ng-template #doNotShowSpinner>

                </ng-template>
            </mat-cell>
        </ng-container>

        <mat-header-row
            *matHeaderRowDef="jobExecStatDisplayedColumns"
        ></mat-header-row>
        <mat-row
            *matRowDef="
                let row;
                columns: jobExecStatDisplayedColumns;
                let element
            "
            class="element-row"
        >
        </mat-row>
```

Typescript Code:

```
displaySpinner: boolean = false;

stop_exec_job(element) {
    if (element.status == "Running" || element.status == "Pending") {
        //Api to stop Job Execution
        this.recommendationService
            .stopJobExecution(element.jobId, "Cancelled")
            .subscribe(data => {
                this.executeJobStop = data;
                //this.changeStatus.push(this.executeJobStop);
                // this.newStatus = new ExampleDataSource();
            });
        this.displaySpinner = false;
        element.status = "Completed";
        this.snakbar.statusBar("Job Execution Stopped", "Sucess");
    } else {
        this.snakbar.statusBar("Job Failed to start", "Failure");
    }
}

re_run_job(element) {
    if (
        element.status == "Cancelled" ||
        element.status == "Completed" ||
        element.status == "Executed" ||
        element.status == "FINISHED"
    ) {
        //Api to Re-Run Job Execution
        this.recommendationService
            .stopJobExecution(element.jobId, "Running")
            .subscribe(data => {
                this.executeJobStop = data;
                //this.changeStatus.push(this.executeJobStop);
                // this.newStatus = new ExampleDataSource();
            });
        this.displaySpinner = true;
        element.status = "Running";
        this.snakbar.statusBar("Job Execution Started", "Sucess");
    } else {
        this.snakbar.statusBar("Job Failed to start", "Failure");
    }
}
```

The stop and re-run button work fine.If i click stop on row 2 then only status of row 2 will change.But if i click on run of row 1 then spinner starts showing for all the rows and similar for stop also.

Comment: you need to set displaySpinner inside every element object instead of global variable. Because its a loop and you need to check displaySpinner logic for every row instead of global single variable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason the `stop_exec_job` function only changes the clicked rows status is because you actually set the status of the rows `element` that you pass to the function.

Your `re_run_job` function also sets the status (which is fine), but the problem is that you use one variable `displaySpinner` in your component, to control the visibility of **all** the spinners on each row.

> To solve your problem, add an additional property on your `element`'s
>   which stores the status of the spinner for each row separately (e.g.
>   `displaySpinner`).

Or if the spinner is based on the status of the element, then you could change your HTML to look something like this (and get rid of your `displaySpinner` variable):

```
<div *ngIf="element.status === 'Pending' || element.status === 'Running'">
  <mat-spinner></mat-spinner>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `displaySpinner` property (which is the global property) of the class is used in all rows. That's why, when you click Re-Run, `displaySpinner` turns `true` and as all rows are having the condition on the same property, they all show the spinner.

Rather than using `displaySpinner`, try to use `element.status`.

Change your below lines:

```html
<div *ngIf="displaySpinner;else doNotShowSpinner">
    <mat-spinner></mat-spinner>
</div>
```

to below:

```html
<div *ngIf="element.status === 'Running';else doNotShowSpinner">
    <mat-spinner></mat-spinner>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Link the spinner to the element status:

```
<!-- Code for Spinner -->
        <ng-container matColumnDef="spinner">
            <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> </mat-header-cell>
            <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
                <div *ngIf="element.status === 'Running'">
                    <mat-spinner></mat-spinner>
                </div>
                <ng-template #doNotShowSpinner>

                </ng-template>
            </mat-cell>
        </ng-container>
```

I would also recommend creating an enum for your Statusses for readability and consistency.